# Non-static methods used in a static context error

Tags: interface, arraylist, compiler-errors, static-methods

I keep getting two errors for this bit of code about non-static methods used in a static context.  This code uses an ArrayList of different objects of birds, cats, and dogs and puts them in the ArrayList called petList using an interface called Pet.
I get the same errors on the 4th and 6th line.

```
    public static void Feed(ArrayList petList){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String petName = input.next();
        contains(petName, petList);

        if(ifThere == true){
            String feed = Pet.feed();
            System.out.println(petName + feed);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Unknown pet");
        }
    }


  public boolean contains (String petName, ArrayList petList){

    boolean ifThere = false;
    int sizeList = petList.size() -1;
    for(int i=0; sizeList > i; i++){
      Pet booleanPet = petList.get(i);
      String booleanName = booleanPet.getName();
      if (booleanName.equals(petName)){
        ifThere = true;
      }
}
return ifThere;
```

}

Comment: That would suggest that contains and feed are not static methods. No way we could help further than that without a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

In short : **You can not call non static method from static method.**

**Solution :**  1) Make  your "contains" method as Static and it will solve the problem.

OR 
    2) (Assume the name of the class is Pet then create an instance of Pet class and call contains method :
your line 4 can be replaced by below code(C# style code) :

```
Pet somePet = new Pet ();
somePet.contains(petName, petList);
```

-- Extra Details: 
Static method is a method which is never specific to any object. e.g. Addtion of 2 number. You 
dont need to instantiate any class to call Math.Add() method because Add is static method.

You can also say that Static is a method which is not a virtual meaning you definitely know 
which method is being called.